# How to configure Rails to use subfolders in models with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-7

I have subfolders inside the models folder:

app/models/foos/bar.rb

Autoload paths is configured in application.rb:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 7.0

    config.public_file_server.enabled = true

    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/')]
```

This works fine in development, but not in test environment.

development.rb:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
```

test.rb

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.eager_load = false
```

spec/models/bar_spec.rb

```
describe Bar do
  ....
```

`rspec` raises NameError:
uninitialized constant Bar

How to autoload the models in test environment?

Rails 7.0.8

Comment: At the very least shouldn’t the test follow the directory hierarchy of the models? Even if that doesn’t make it work it sure sucks less trying to figure out where things are.

Comment: What you're doing here makes no sense. With Zeitwerk if you nest `bar.rb` in a folder below an autoloading root it will autovivify the module and the constant will be loaded as `Foos/Bar`.  Not only are you making the code harder to find but you're also introducing potential bugs and confusion. Just don't man. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, it was the .rspec file.

Needs to be

```
--require rails_helper
```